# How to save the selected worksheet without specifying sheet name or number

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to save the active/selected worksheet without having to specify `sheets(1)`?

The code below is execute via command button and will take the worksheet "Quote" copy to a new workbook, and then prompt to save under the downloads directory.

I'm also trying to get that button to save whichever sheet is selected, it could be Quote or Sheet1, but not both.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click() ' save worksheet
    'Gets the name of the currently visible worksheet
    Filename = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    'Puts the worksheet into its own workbook
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy
    
    'Saves the workbook - uses the name of the worksheet as the name of the new workbook
    'Filename = Range("A1")
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    Dim NameFile As Variant
    
    With Worksheets("Quote")
        'NameFile = .Range("A1") & "_" & .Range("B5") & "_" & ".xls"
    End With

    NameFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\" & NameFile, Filefilter:="Fichier Excel (*.xls), *.xls")

    If NameFile = False Then
        MsgBox "File not saved"
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NameFile
    End If
    
    'Closes the newly created workbook so you are still looking at the original workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: `With Worksheets("Quote")` ---> `With ActiveSheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy the Active Worksheet to a New Workbook

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click() ' save worksheet
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    
    sws.Copy
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only
    
    Dim dwbName: dwbName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\" & dws.Name, _
        FileFilter:="Fichier Excel (*.xls), *.xls")
    
    If dwbName = False Then
        MsgBox "File not saved", vbCritical
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dwbName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Now 'dws' and 'dwb' are invalid but still 'Not Nothing'.
    ' On the other hand, 'sws' still points to the (initial) source worksheet.
    ' If you need to reference the source workbook use:
    'Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = sws.Parent
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This Sub creates a new Workbook from a sheet. But you must have a way to call this Sub of every sheet, or a better place is a button in the ribbon witch in it's handler: Call NewBookOfSheet(ActiveSheet).

```
Public Sub NewBookOfSheet(ws As Worksheet)
   Dim nwb As Workbook, curwb As Workbook
   If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Set curwb = ws.Parent
   Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
   curwb.Activate
   ws.Select
   ws.Copy Before:=nwb.Sheets(1)
   nwb.Activate
   Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ws.Name
End Sub
```